# Razor view with nested model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a nested class such as :

```
public class Jar
{
    public IEnumerable<NailClippings> Nails { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<People> Donors { set; get; }
}
```

My controller passes a single `Jar` to my view, string typed as

```
@model Test.ViewModels.Jar
```

I can loop through the contents of `Nails` and `Donors` easily with something like this

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Nails)
```

My issue is with using HTML helpers to generate Display names for me

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nails.Length)
```

I have come up with a solution by changing the type of the inner nested classes to `List`, appending `.ToList()` at the end of my queries and changing the line to

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nails[0].Length)
```

Being forced to use `List` and have an index `[0]` to display a name is goofy to me. Is there an alternative method for referencing inner nested class attributes?

**Edit**: View

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nails[0].Length)</th>
        .
        .
    </tr>
    @foreach(var item in Model.Nails){
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Length</td>
        .
        .
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
model.Nails[0].Length
```

You could use

```
model.Nails.First().Length
```

Without having to convert to a `List`.

Comment: What if Nails contains no items?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky This works if no items are in the list. I think using [0] will break it...Just tested it. It works with both methods if the list is empty. This solution is much prettier than what I had used

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I haven't verified, but I think `DisplayNameFor` just uses reflection to get the field name or any attributes to get the display label, so `First()` is not actually called (which would result in an exception).  I could be horribly wrong though...

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to be writing any loops in your views. It makes them so ugly.

Simply define a corresponding display template for the collection type. So for example you would create `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/NailClippings.cshtml` partial view that will be strongly typed to a single element of the collection:

```
@model NailClippings
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Length)
    </td>
    .
    .
</tr>
```

and now inside your main view it's as simple as:

```
@model Jar
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Length</th>
            .
            .
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Nails)
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Display/editor templates work by convention. So here when inside your main view you use `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Nails)`, ASP.NET MVC will analyze the type of the `Nails` property and will see that it is an `IEnumerable<NailClippings>` collection. So it will start looking for a corresponding display template first inside `~/Views/CurrentController/DisplayTemplates/NailClippings.cshtml`, then inside `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/NailClippings.cshtml` and finally it will fallback to the [`default display template`](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html). When a template is selected this template will automatically be executed for you by ASP.NET MVC for each element of the collection property so that you never have to worry about things like writing some loops in your views, worry about indexes, ...

This also works with editor templates: `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Nails)` will look for `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/NailClippings.cshtml`. The bonus you get here is that the generated input fields will have correct names and you when you submit the form, the default model binder will automatically rehydrate your view model that the HttpPost action is taking as argument from the request.

Basically if you respect the conventions that the framework is following you will make your life much easier.

Comment: This method is quite elegant. I will try this out. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's quite elegant. It relies on the conventions that are built directly into the framework. You never need to write a single loop in your views if you respect those conventions. Basically everytime you write a loop in your view an alarm should ring in your head telling you that you are doing it wrong and there's a much better way.

Comment: I was able to get this working with a smaller test project but was not able to get it working in my real project. I had set up my display template and view just as you had, but an error was thrown regarding wrong types. In context, `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Nails)` tries to pass in a type `IEnumerable<NailClipping>`, while the template was expecting a type `NailClipping`. Quote:`executed for you by ASP.NET MVC for each element of the collection property`. How do I perform this behavior? Also, for future users, it seems that you need to use `UIHints` in your model

Comment: If you use `UIHint` or specify the template name as second argument to the DisplayFor helper you are violating the standard conventions and now your template will be passed an `IEnumerable<NailClipping>` instead of `NailClipping`. That's a bit unfortunate but it's how the designers decided to implement it. So I would recommend you rely on the conventions illustrated in my answer. So  UIHint and specify a custom editor template name works great for normal properties but with collections (everything that's `IEnumerable<T>`) do not use it and use `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/T.cshtml`.

Comment: I suspect that you decorated your collection property with the UIHint attribute, have you? If so, your template will be passed an `IEnumerable<NailClipping>` and so you should loop inside it getting you to your initial problem :-)

Comment: I tried a combination of using `UIHint` and `@model IEnumberable`.... Turns out my issue was with file naming: `NailClippings` vs `NailClipping` :(. It works now. Also, I had initially marked this is the answer but then removed it. I got caught up in the moment and then realized that although this answer is awesome information, it doesn't quite answer my question. In your example, you use `<th>Length</th>` instead of a HTML helper. I'd like to be able to, for example, use data annotations to change the displayname so it changes site wide.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just use `item` variable of loop

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.Length)
```

UPDATE another option for you is creating partial view for Nails displaying. It will be strongly typed to `IEnumerable<NailClippings>` and all properties will be available:

```
@Html.Partial("_Nails", Model.Nails)
```

Nails partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<NailClippings>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Length)</th>
        .
        .
    </tr>
    @foreach(var item in Model){
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Length)</td>
        .
        .
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: I probably should have posted more code. item is only valid within the scope the the `foreach` statement. It wouldn't make sense to alternate between name and data within a table. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I think this sample code is useful for nested model class

```
@model ViewModels.MyViewModels.Theme

@Html.LabelFor(Model.Theme.name)
@foreach (var category in Model.Theme)
{
   @Html.LabelFor(category.name)
   @foreach(var product in theme.Products)
   {
      @Html.LabelFor(product.name)
      @foreach(var order in product.Orders)
      {
          @Html.TextBoxFor(order.Quantity)
          @Html.TextAreaFor(order.Note)
          @Html.EditorFor(order.DateRequestedDeliveryFor)
      }
   }
}
```